# Split text by comma from custom html pasted in textarea via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having some custom html pasted in textarea. I want to split its intensity values by comma. I am able to access all its values but these are coming in a single row without any comma. Please take look at me code and give me your valuable suggestion.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var $intensity = $("<div/>").html($('.textarea').val()).find("intensity").find("intensity").text();
console.log($intensity);
});
// It should give 64, 88, 32, 53
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='textarea'>
<intensity><theta>28</theta><da>4.0</da><intensity>64</intensity><h>1</h></intensity><intensity><theta>32</theta><da>1.3</da><intensity>88</intensity><h>1</h></intensity><intensity><theta>21</theta><da>3.8</da><intensity>32</intensity><h>1</h></intensity><intensity><theta>46</theta><da>2.4</da><intensity>53</intensity><h>1</h></intensity>
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.map()` to get the desired result and then use `.join(", ")` to convert it from an array to a string.

```
.map(function(){
   return $.trim($(this).text());
}).get().join(", ");
```

as in:

```
 var $intensity = $("<div/>").html($('.textarea').val()).find("intensity").find("intensity").map(function(){
        return $.trim($(this).text());
     }).get().join(", ");
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $intensity = $("<div/>").html($('.textarea').val()).find("intensity").find("intensity").map(function(){
               return $.trim($(this).text());
            }).get().join(", ");
  console.log($intensity);
});
// It should give 64, 88, 32, 53
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='textarea'>
<intensity><theta>28</theta><da>4.0</da><intensity>64</intensity><h>1</h></intensity><intensity><theta>32</theta><da>1.3</da><intensity>88</intensity><h>1</h></intensity><intensity><theta>21</theta><da>3.8</da><intensity>32</intensity><h>1</h></intensity><intensity><theta>46</theta><da>2.4</da><intensity>53</intensity><h>1</h></intensity>
</textarea>
```

To get the max value of the array you can use `Math.max.apply(null, $intensity)`

**Array Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $intensity = $("<div/>").html($('.textarea').val()).find("intensity").find("intensity").map(function(){
               return $.trim($(this).text());
            }).get();
  console.log(Math.max.apply(null, $intensity));
});
// It should give 64, 88, 32, 53
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='textarea'>
<intensity><theta>28</theta><da>4.0</da><intensity>64</intensity><h>1</h></intensity><intensity><theta>32</theta><da>1.3</da><intensity>88</intensity><h>1</h></intensity><intensity><theta>21</theta><da>3.8</da><intensity>32</intensity><h>1</h></intensity><intensity><theta>46</theta><da>2.4</da><intensity>53</intensity><h>1</h></intensity>
</textarea>
```

Comment: Sir, can you please help me so that I can store these values in an array and find maximum value

Comment: I have tried it by using: $('input[name="max_value"]').val(Math.max.apply(Math, $intensity).toArray()); But it is not working :(

Comment: @SweetyDheeraj Check the second demo